# Upgrading Laptop Wi-Fi Adapter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop

I plan to upgrade my laptop's Wifi PCI Express Half-Card. The laptop is a bit old, 2011, 2nd Generation Intel® Core™ i5 Processor with an Intel HM65 Chipset. Currently it has a Wireless N Adapter with NO Bluetooth.

I plan to add Bluetooth 4.0 LE and possibly Wireless AC. And that brings me to my question. I doubt that my laptop antennas support 2.4 GHz as well as 5 GHz. Will it be a waste to update to Wireless AC give the antennas cannot handle that frequency?

Comment: 802.11ac is 5.0 GHz only standard.  However, dual-band cards do exist due to them supporting previous revisions of the 802.11 standard.  If your current adapter isn’t dual band then you only have a single antenna which means you will not be able to use newer cards to their full potential.  You might be better of with an external wireless adapter.  You will be unlikely to actually use 802.11ac even if the card supports it and they sell USB BT transmitters

Comment: The 5 Ghz range is about the double frequency of the 2.4 GHz range, so there's a good chance the antennas will work (though maybe not at peak efficency). FWIW, my desktop WLAN PCI WLAN adapter uses the same antennas for 2.4 Ghz and 5 GHz.

Comment: My Atheros WiFi adapter only supported 2.4GHz, but it had two antennas. So I happily replaced it with a dual band Intel 7260HMW-AC and connected the two existing antennas to it. The result is that I have a pretty decent 5GHz connection, but the speed fluctuates constantly, every minute or so (does not cause the connection to drop, but does cause a re-association message in the router log). As for the 2.4GHz, it became pretty awful and slow if 40MHz channel is used, I had to force it to 20GHz wide channel to make it bearable (but still slow). Apparently there is sense in replacing the antennas?